# Read a tab delimited txt file and Display it in reverse order

Tags: asp-classic

I have a tab delimited text file that uses a Classic ASP page to read it and display it from top to bottom.  Here is the text file:

```
Email                     Division      Course   TotalIncorrect Score   DATE_TIME
1steve.perry@gov.gc.ca    National      BI Course   5           40%     2014-01-23 16:38:55
2sylvie.smith@gov.gc.ca   B - H - J - L BI Course   5           100%    2014-01-31 14:56:34
3Jen.peter@gov.gc.ca      D - F - K     BI Course   5           100%    2014-02-07 18:11:22
4BigJimMcBob@gov.gc.ca    National      BI Course   5           40%     2014-01-23 16:38:55
5Tony.Montana@gov.gc.ca   B - H - J - L BI Course   5           100%    2014-01-31 14:56:34
```

Here is the ASP code which reads the txt file:

```
<%

Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
dim import_file,counter,line,fso,objFile
import_file="QuizScores.txt"
counter=0
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FileExists("D:\Vignette\QuizScores.txt"))=true Then

set objFile = fso.opentextfile(server.mappath(import_file))

str_imported_data="<table style='text-align: left; width: 98%; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial Narrow;' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='2' border='0'>"
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream


line = split(objFile.ReadLine, vbTab)

if (counter Mod 2 = 0) And (counter = 0) then
  str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<tr bgcolor='#3C3C3C' style='font-weight: bold; color:white;'>"
Elseif (counter Mod 2 = 0) Then
  str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<tr bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>"
Else
  str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<tr bgcolor='#FFFFE5'>"
end if

counter=counter+1
total_records=ubound(line)

for i=0 to total_records
  if ((i=0) or (i=6)) then
     str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<td style='font-weight: bold;'><font size='-1'>"&line(i)&"</td>"
  else
     str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<td><font size='-1'>"&line(i)&"</td>"
  end if
next
  str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"</tr>" & chr(13)
Loop
str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<caption><b>Project Systems Solution Real Property Course Test Scores</b></caption></table>"

objFile.Close

response.Write str_imported_data
set fso=nothing

Else
  Response.Write("Test Scores File does NOT exist.")
End If

%>
```

I would like to have the asp page read the txt file but reverse the order so that the most recent record would appear at the top of the table and the oldest at the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.  I am fairly new at ASP!

Thanks

Here is my REVISED CODE April 1st 2014:

---

```
<%
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
dim import_file,counter,line,fso,objFile
Dim array_line(), array_column()

import_file="QuizScores.txt"

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FileExists("D:\Vignette\QuizScores.txt")) Then

set objFile = fso.opentextfile(server.mappath(import_file))
counter=0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    array_line(counter) = objFile.ReadLine
    counter=counter+1
    Redim Preserve array_line(counter)
Loop
objFile.Close
set fso=nothing

str_imported_data="<table style='text-align: left; width: 98%; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial Narrow;' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='2' border='0'>"
total_records=ubound(array_line)

for i_row=total_records to 0 step -1
    array_column = split(array_line(i_row), vbTab)

    if (i_row Mod 2 = 0) And (i_row = 0) then
        s_bgcolor = "bgcolor='#3C3C3C' style='font-weight: bold; color:white;'"
    Elseif (i_row Mod 2 = 0) Then
        s_bgcolor = "bgcolor='#EEEEEE'"
    Else
        s_bgcolor = "bgcolor='#FFFFE5'"
    end if

    str_imported_data=str_imported_data & "<tr>" & vbCrLf

    for i_col = 0 to 6
        if ((i=0) or (i=6)) then
            str_imported_data = str_imported_data & "<td " & s_bgcolor & "><font size='-1' style='font-weight: bold;'>" & array_column(i_col) & "</td>" & vbCrLf
        else
            str_imported_data = str_imported_data & "<td " & s_bgcolor & "><font size='-1'>" & array_column(i_col) & "</td>" & vbCrLf
        end if
    next 'i_col
    str_imported_data = str_imported_data & "</tr>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
next 'i_row

str_imported_data = "<caption><b>Project Systems Solution Real Property Course Test Scores</b></caption></table>" & vbCrLf & str_imported_data

response.Write (str_imported_data)
Else
Response.Write("Test Scores File does NOT exist.")
End If
%>
```

Comment: Read it into an array / collection, reverse / sort it, then display it....

Comment: Thanks.  Conceptually I know that is what is required, but I am not quite sure how to go about doing it.  I was considering reading each row of the text file into a two dimensional array but like I said, my ASP skills are not quite at that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but won't have many errors.
FYI: I recommend you notice the way I spaced things out; for more readable code.
Oh and if memory serves, putting "bgcolor" attribute into TR does not work in most browsers, which is why I moved it to the TDs.

```
<%
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
dim import_file,counter,line,fso,objFile
import_file="QuizScores.txt"
counter=0
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If (fso.FileExists("D:\Vignette\QuizScores.txt")) Then

    set objFile = fso.opentextfile(server.mappath(import_file))
    counter=0
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        array_line(counter) = objFile.ReadLine
        counter=counter+1
    Loop
    objFile.Close
    set fso=nothing

    str_imported_data="<table style='text-align: left; width: 98%; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial Narrow;' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='2' border='0'>"
    total_records=ubound(array_line)

    for i_row=total_records to 0 step -1
        array_column = split(array_line(i_row), vbTab)

        if (i_row Mod 2 = 0) And (i_row = 0) then
            s_bgcolor = "bgcolor='#3C3C3C' style='font-weight: bold; color:white;'"
        Elseif (i_row Mod 2 = 0) Then
            s_bgcolor = "bgcolor='#EEEEEE'"
        Else
            s_bgcolor = "bgcolor='#FFFFE5'"
        end if

        str_imported_data=str_imported_data & "<tr>" & vbCrLf

        for i_col = 0 to 6
            if ((i=0) or (i=6)) then
                str_imported_data = str_imported_data & "<td " & s_bgcolor & "><font size='-1' style='font-weight: bold;'>" & array_column(i_col) & "</td>" & vbCrLf
            else
                str_imported_data = str_imported_data & "<td " & s_bgcolor & "><font size='-1'>" & array_column(i_col) & "</td>" & vbCrLf
            end if
        next 'i_col
        str_imported_data = str_imported_data & "</tr>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    next 'i_row

    str_imported_data = "<caption><b>Project Systems Solution Real Property Course Test Scores</b></caption></table>" & vbCrLf & str_imported_data

    response.Write (str_imported_data)
Else
  Response.Write("Test Scores File does NOT exist.")
End If
%>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for providing me with this possible solution.  I have been trying it for a while now and am not able to get it to work.  One thing I wondered about is total_records=ubound(line).  line is not used anywhere else in the program.  Is there possibly another typo somewhere that I am missing?  Thanks again.

Comment: Ooops! total_records=ubound(array_line)

Comment: Please feel free to mark my code as solution. I can use the points :-)

Comment: I checked my log files and I am getting the following error message:  Type_mismatch:_'array_line' 80

Comment: Ah you probably need to dim array_line() before you start reading the file into array_line(). I recommend googling "vbscript arrays". I want to fall on the side of helping you without doing ALL the work :-)

Comment: There is a great tutorial here on how to set up and use arrays, including - make sure you read the part about using "preserve" so you can set up an array at the beginning to be "variable size" like this: dim array_line() and then later use redim. Here is the tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_arrays.htm

Comment: I am so close, but now I am getting the subscript out of range error - 800a0009|Subscript_out_of_range.  I have read your tutorial and dimmed the arrays but cannot see my error.

Comment: Did you use redim? Please show your code. You still haven't even upvoted my answer.

Comment: @ScotterMonkey Pushie you aren't ya, if he doesn't want to upvote you he doesn't have to, nought more desperate than asking for upvotes. Maybe once he get's your solution to work then he'll upvote it.

Comment: I will be pleased to vote and give you points once I get it to work.  Like I said, I am new to ASP so I have not quite figured out all of the nuances of arrays.  It appears as though that is the issue here.  My errors are related to the arrays not loading up properly.

Comment: Sorry. I never asked for votes before. Just the other day I got banned from asking questions because I asked a question in the wrong area and the only way to get my privileges back is to get votes. So yeah, I guess I was a bit desperate, heh. Sorry.

Comment: No Problem.  I will vote now because what you have added so far is very close and I will keep at it until I figure it out.

Comment: I am trying to vote up, but I need 15 reputations to be able to vote.

Comment: Please post your code that you have so far and I'll modify it to make it work. I was reluctant to do this for you ONLY because I thought it would inhibit your learning for me to do all of it for you. But if you want it, I'll do it. However, if you want to do it yourself, I recommend studying the link I gave you, particularly the part about REDIM and then figure out where to add REDIM in. Again, though, post your code if you want help and I'll give it.

Comment: @ScotterMonkey:  I added the revised code at the bottom of the original post.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Change this to look like this (slight re-order):

Redim Preserve array_line(counter+1) :
array_line(counter) = objFile.ReadLine :
counter=counter+1

I'm putting that "+1" in there because I'm not sure if you can dim an array to be (0) in size.
SO this will work but it will also cause one last line at the end that is empty. Note the colons I put in to mean carriage return because this box won't let me format code.